# Unable to connect to Office Communicator 2007

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, office-communicator-2007, ms-office-communicator

I'm trying to use "Microsoft Office Communicator 2007 R2" from my home desktop. I've connected to VPN of my company's network, installed Microsoft Office Communicator 2007 R2 & now trying to connect to it but it connects only sometimes. Most of the times, it gives error

```
"Cannot sign in to Communicator. You may have entered your sign-in address, user name, or password incorrectly, or the authetication service may be incompatible with this version of the program. If your sign-in information is correct and the problem persistes, please contact your system administrator."
```

Can any one tell me what could be the reason & how can I connect to my office communicator in first attempt through VPN?

Thanks!